# Accessing a class object within a class from a class

Tags: c++, class, iterator, nodes

I know this title is a bit confusing but a diagram will probably help. 
in one file:

```
#ifndef ...
#def  ...
#includes (including OListiterator.h>
template <class T>
class OList;
template <class T>
Class OListiterator{
    friend class OList<T>::OList;
    typename OList<T>::Node* iiter;
};
function defs;
#endif
```

in another:

```
#ifndef ...
#def ...
#includes (one is OList.h)
template<class T>
class OListiterator;
template <class T>
Class OList{
     friend class OListiterator<T>::OListiterator;
     public:
          class Node{
          };
      //things
};
//functions
#endif
```

This is what myself and the TA assisting me would have thought would work, but I am thrown the error: Node does not name a type in OList. Does anybody know why/how I can fix this? Let me know if I need to post more.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a dependency here. `OList` needs `OListIterator`, and vice versa. The way to solve this is to change your design so this dependency is not needed. Try placing your `OListIterator` design so it can be used inside the `OList`.

Comment: I have the dependencies worked out. I already declared template<clas T> class OList in OListiterator, and worked out everything so that OListiterator and OList are accessible in each other. It is ONLY Node that cannot be accessed

Answer (score 0):

You need a forward declaration of `class OList`:

```
// forward declaration
template <class T>
class OList;

template <class T>
class OListiterator{
    friend class OList<T>::OList;
    typename OList<T>::Node* iiter;
};

template <class T>
class OList{
     friend class OListiterator<T>::OListiterator;
public:
    class Node{
    };
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5312c555ac410470)

Note that `friend class OList<T>::OList;` is equivalent to just `friend class OList<T>;` because `OList<T>::OList` is class name injected in scope of `OList<T>`.

Comment: @Anton I have already done the forward declaration and the friend class declarations as you had shown.

Comment: @Eric most likely you don't include a header file containing definition of `OList` in some of code which uses `OListiterator`. Have a look at the demo I provided and see where your code is different.

Comment: I removed one of the function definitions in my OListiterator constructor, which called OList and set it to the first node, removing the issue. When I then compiled, however, I am now getting an issue in OList (which also calls OListiterator) for invalid use of incommplete type OListiterator.

Comment: @Eric wait, do you mean you have these template class definitions in .cpp files?

Comment: @Eric so you include .h files from themselves?

Comment: yes, I have pound included each .h file below the ifndef and defs. OList contains OListiterator and OListiterator contains OList. see above.

Comment: @Eric you must instantiate `OListiterator<T>` only after a definition of `ONode<T>`. See [this demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/248c352c8fa60a86) to see how it fails when you don't do it. As you don't provide your code in the way that the error can be reproduced, I can't give more advice.

Comment: how do I define Node<T> before instantiating OListiterator<T>?

Comment: that demo looks exactly with the way my program is structured.

Comment: wouldn't I need them? I have them within ifndefs so they don't cause an infinite loop. Both OList and OListiterator compile fine, it is OListiteratorTest (the test file) that throws the errors for me.

Answer (score 0):

When you name the member `Node` of `OList` as a friend, the compiler needs the entire definition of `OList` to ensure that there is such a member.

The solution would be to break the dependency. Why does a list node need to have access to the list iterator's internals? Seems to me like it should be the other way around.

Comment: I think this may be the issue as well. When I try to breakup the dependency, however, then my OList class breaks. How can I give it the entire definition of OList??